# javascript oninput fires only once?

Tags: javascript, html, cgi

I'm having a JavaScript function fires-only-once issue.

I started out with a more concise structure in the function, but broke it out into discrete ops to see if I could figure anything out. Acts exactly the same.

In my HTML, within the HEAD tags, I have:

```
<SCRIPT>
function onCharInput()
{
var conpagechars = document.getElementById("pagecontentx").innerHTML;
var conpagecharcount = conpagechars.length.toString();
document.getElementById("pccount").innerHTML = conpagecharcount;
console.log('test',conpagecharcount);
}
</SCRIPT>
```

Within an opening CGI textarea input element, I have this:

```
id="pagecontentx" oninput="onCharInput()"
```

Elsewhere on the page, I have this:

```
<span id="pccount"></span>
```

When I type something into the text area, the span updates with the correct size of the content -- exactly once. After that, it does nothing. I can add characters, delete characters... nothing. After adding the console call, with the firefox console open, I see results also just once. Near as I can tell, the function is never called again after the first time.

TIA

Comment: CGI is a means for a webserver to talk to an external program in order to process an HTTP request. You are dealing with client side JavaScript. There is not HTTP involved so there is no CGI involved.

Comment: It's a CGI form. My concern was that something was different because of that. That's why I mentioned it, not because I thought the server was doing any work once the page was up. But yes, of course you are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for CGI textareas, the data is fetched this way:

```
var conpagechars = document.getElementById("pagecontentx").value;
```

Not this way:

```
var conpagechars = document.getElementById("pagecontentx").innerHTML;
```

Simple enough. ;)

Answer (score 1):

The function fires every time there is an input event, you are just reading the same string every time.

The `innerHTML` of a `<textarea>` represents its **default** value.

You need to read the `value` property to get its **current** value.

```js
document.querySelector("textarea").addEventListener("input", log);

function log(event) {
  console.log("Log function is firing");
  console.log("Current value: " + this.value);
  console.log("Default value: " + this.innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<textarea>This is the default value</textarea>
```